# Orientações diferentes no smartphone e tablet

Tags: java, android

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um app e preciso que a tela fique em portrait para smartphones e portrait/landscape para tablets. O cliente não quer aceitar aplicativos distintos e não quer deixar a orientação destravada no smartphone.
Minha solução foi criar um bool que altera o valor conforme o tamanho da tela, porém a aplicação fecha no smartphone ao inicia-la quando o dispositivo está na landscape. 
A classe principal extende a classe NoRotateScreen, o código dentro dela é:

```
   boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
   if (!tabletSize) {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   }
```

O arquivo que seta o arquivo boolean está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

O que posso fazer?

Comment: Faz um layout pra celular e outro para tablet, depois faz um if pra ver se eh um tablet ou um celular.

Comment: O cliente não quer aceitar.

Comment: Pedro da uma olhada na minha resposta vê se vc entendeu

Answer (score 2):

Cria uma layout na pasta **layout-large** ou na **layout-xlarge**, use o mesmo layout que vc usa para o celular(mesmo nome), mas vai mudar o id de algum componete.
depois no codigo vc faz algo do tipo:

```
        // tablet
        if (findViewById(R.id.menu) != null) {
            // esse id.menu só vai existir no layout com tablet
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
```

Comment: Testei aqui funcionou, qualquer dúvida pode perguntar.

Comment: Fora do contexto.

Comment: Como assim fora do contexto ??

Comment: Bom te mostrei um exemplo de como diferenciar um tablet de um celular, e fazer o tablet poder ficar Tanto landscape como portrait, e o celular somente portrait; que pelo que eu entendi era oque vc queria...

Comment: Solucionei o problema, durante a splash screen o aplicativo fica liberado a rotação, após isso, ele bloquia já na tela de login.

Answer (score 0):

Use esse método para saber se o device é tablet:

```
public static boolean isTabletDevice(final Context ct) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) { // honeycomb
            /**
             * testa o tamanho da tela usando reflection porque isLayoutSizeAtLeast
             * só está disponível a partir do skd int 11
             */
            Configuration con = ct.getResources().getConfiguration();
            try {
                Method mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast = con.getClass().getMethod(
                        "isLayoutSizeAtLeast", int.class);
                Boolean r = (Boolean) mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast.invoke(con,
                        0x00000004); // Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
                return r;
            } catch (Exception x) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```