# Como saber se é um tablet ou um smartphone?

Tags: android

Como posso eu saber se estou a trabalhar num  *tablet* ou um *smartphone* com a API do Android?

Hoje em dia as resoluções, dpi são quase a mesma coisa entre *tablets* e *smartphones* e fica complicado saber em que dispositivo estou a trabalhar.

A ideia é que a minha aplicação fique **portrait** para *smartphones* e **portrait/landscape** para *tablets*.

Já vi [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7607/7210) mas não resolve o meu problema.

**Há alguma forma de saber se estou em *tablet* ou *smartphone* com toda a certeza?**

Comment: Hoje em dia tem uns smartphones que são maiores do que alguns tablets, antigos ou não. Ou seja, o diferença entre conceitos de tablets e smartphones está ficando muito embaçada, portanto você deveria escolher outro parametro para ser basear, como por exemplo o tamanho da tela (sim, em polegadas)

Comment: Como é que eu chego a esse tamanho?

Comment: Não faço ideia, apenas to dizendo uma possibilidade de como resolver o seu problema ;)

Comment: Jorge, eu costumo usar o "sufixo" `large` (p.e: `values-large`) em meus resources. Mas ja não tenho a compleeeta certeza se ela não irá dar falsos positivos (Tipo um galaxy note 3 da vida ou LG G3). Agora deu vontade de testar...

Comment: Testa e me diz :D Nunca me fiei muito nesses sufixos.

Comment: Testei agora, no GN3 o `large` não pegou, o que é aceitável. Usando meu Nexus 7, ele funciona. No guideline do Android, ele fala sobre o sw600-xx para tablets de 7", sw720-xx para tablets de 10" e ainda comenta sobre o xlarge. Tente dar uma olhada nesses 3 pra ver se atende.

Comment: O meu problema é que a minha app tem de funcionar em todo lado, mas em smartphones só funca em portrait.

Comment: @Wakim Estou a experimentar com o sony xperia z e está a assumir como tablet :(

Comment: @JorgeB. Testei com esse Sony Xperia Z (mesmo tamanho de tela e mesmo dpi que o GN3) e deu certo. Existe também o Sony Xperia Tablet Z. Lembrando que eu uso o `layout-large` por exemplo.

Comment: @Wakim Deu certo como assim? Assumiu large? Ou não?

Comment: Assumiu como não no xperia.

Comment: E no m705f? Esse a mim assume-me como não large :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como essa pergunta é interessante e essa questão de identificar corretamente Tablet's me trouxe problemas também, que consegui resolver. Deixo a minha solução para o problema:

Como eu disse, estava usando tanto o sufixo `large` quanto o sufixo `sw-600dp` para layout's e recursos para **Tablet's**, o `large` como compatibilidade já que o `sw-600dp` não é reconhecido nas versões anteriores ao 3.0 (Honeycomb) do Android.

Porém alguns devices como o **HTC One** e o **Xperia Z1** e outros que possuem tela de 1920x1080 com densidade de aproximadamente 320 dpi acabavam usando os recursos e layout's do sufixo `large`, quebrando minha lógica e minha UI.

Minha solução foi abolir de vez o uso do sufixo `large`, dado que olhando o [**Dashboard** da plataforma](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform), não aparecem dados relevantes sobre o uso do Honeycomb (3.0) e no meu Dashboard do **Google Play** aparece **0.46%** dos usuários **totais** (não apenas do meu app), por isso decidi ignorar para não causar detrimento a outros usuários de dispositivos mais modernos.

Resumindo: Coloque os recursos de Tablet com sufixo `sw-600dp`, seja `landscape` ou `portrait` e não em `large` por compatibilidade.

Comment: E apanhas todos os tablets com esse sufixo e nenhum smartphone?

Comment: Eu testei esse qualificador `sw600dp` naquele xperia e funcionou. O problema era o `large` que eu tinha deixado como compatibilidade.

Comment: O Problema é que eu tenho um tablet chinês com 320dp e vai dar asneira de certeza. Resolvi o problema doutra forma, mas foi gambiarra.

Comment: Ah, não cogitei eles porque não consigo testar. O problema é que fazer uma regra só pra eles poderá acabar englobando um phone high end. Se puder testar o `sw320dp` nele e num xperia ou Galaxy Note no emulador.

Comment: Vai dar asneira de certeza. Eu tenho aqui esse tablet e um smart Samsung Express, os dois com 320dp. Ai está o meu problema.

Comment: Mas esta parece ser a melhor resposta para a MAIORIA dos aparelhos.

Answer (score 1):

Sua resposta está aqui

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet

Link para o assunto:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali

Se você ler todo o tópico, eles explicam como definir um valor booleano em um arquivo de valor específico (como res/values-sw600dp/);

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Porque o qualificador sw600dp só é válida para as plataformas acima android 3.2. Se você quer ter certeza que essa técnica funciona em todas as plataformas (antes 3,2), criar o mesmo arquivo na pasta res / valores-xlarge:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Em seguida, no arquivo de valor "standard" (como res/values/), você define o boolean para false:

```
<resources>
   <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Então em sua activity, você pode obter este valor e verificar se você está rodando em um dispositivo do tamanho de tablet:

```
boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
if (tabletSize) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Usei isso assumiu o meu *tablet* como telefone.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu penso que voce deveria optar mesmo por "filtrar" por tamanho de tela e não por ser tablet ou smartphone, ou seja, se o ecran for grande mesmo que não seja um tablet vai ficar bem...
Veja aqui, deve ajudar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet

Comment: O que queres dizer com tamanho da tela? As polegadas?

Comment: Usando o getSize(), existem vários exemplos
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055458/detect-7-inch-and-10-inch-tablet-programmatically

Comment: Nessa questão o tamanho da tela é mal calculado!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você nao deveria focar se é tablet ou se é smartphone para um comportamento da sua app, pois como foi dito existe smartphone que é do tamanho ou maior q um tablet (tal como ja foi dito). No meu ponto de vista seria definir um comportamento para uma determinada resolução, pois pode ocorrer do user estar com um smartphone e você querer que sua app se comportasse como um tablet, por causa da resolução.

Enfim, não sei se da certo mais e se usasse css na sua app com media query
    [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102161/how-to-use-media-queries-for-android-devices-with-android-version-2-2-1-and-2-3

Comment: É mesmo obrigatário que seja assim, porque landscape em telemóvel, mesmo nos maiores fica horrível. E nos tablets mesmo os mais pequenos fica bem.