# Como detectar a resolução de tela para aplicar o layout no android?

Tags: android, android-layout, resolução-de-tela

Como  detectar determinado tamanho de tela e aplicar o layout especifico ? Exemplo:

Criei uma pasta layout chamada "layout_480x800", nela vai estar os layouts para essa resolução,tenho também uma pasta layout chamada "layout_720x1280" no qual vai se adequar ao meu outro celular, e preciso que de acordo com o tipo de tela, o layout seja aplicado. Tem algum código de exemplo para me mostrar ?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28113/como-saber-se-%C3%A9-um-tablet-ou-um-smartphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, você deve utilizar pastas com essa nomenclatura.

> **layout-xlarge** telas de ao menos 960dp x 720dp
>
> **layout-large** telas de ao menos 640dp x 480dp
>
> **layout-normal** telas de ao menos 470dp x 320dp
>
> **layout-small** telas de ao menos 426dp x 320dp

Dentro dessas pastas você cria os arquivos de layouts(xml) com o mesmo nome.
O sistema fara a verificação implicitamente pra você e determinará qual utilizar em tempo de execução. Não precisa se preocupar no código java.

Como você fará uma tela para cada tamanho sugiro que estude um pouco sobre Fragment pois provavelmente você irá precisar.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Muuuuito simples, amigo. Utilize isso e desenvolva!

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

                if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 480) 
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Igual ou maior que 480dp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setContentView(R.layout.layout_480x800);

                } else if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp == 720) 

                {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Igual a 720dp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setContentView(R.layout.layout_720x1280);
                }
```

"Vamos juntos ao avanço"

Comment: Obrigado, só mais uma coisa, aqui está dando por exemplo no tabhost, um valor nulo,  o código para detectar a resolução eu coloquei dentro do oncreate. Preciso fazer algo além disso ? E outra, a pasta não está sendo reconhecida como a que criei, só mostra a do LAYOUT padrão mesmo : / .

Comment: Muito obrigado.Consegui resolver =D .

Comment: Marca como +1 se eu te ajudei :p